# Code to store a file's lines in a char double pointer is storing the same line in all elements

Tags: c, pointers

I want to make a code that reads a file and stores each line of it into a string. On the other hand, I store these strings into another array, which makes a char double pointer. The code is printing the file rightly, but when I try to print a string (one of the lines) randomly it always outputs the last line of the file ("{").

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //I Open the file
    FILE* file_1 = fopen ("Caso2.ll", "r");
    char string[1000];
    //I create a double pointer to char of size 1000 (big enough to store any string)
    char ** string_2 = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *)*1000);
    int i =0;
    //While fgets is different from NULL
    while (fgets(string, 1000, file_1)!= NULL)
    {
        //I define each element of string_2 as a char pointer (string)
        string_2[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
        //and attribute string to string_2, thus storing the read line into it
        string_2[i] = string;
        //I print string_2
        printf("%s", string_2[i]);
        i++;
    }
    //Until now everything is okay. The code is printing the file okay.
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    //Here is where the error is. When I try to print a random element of 
    //string_2, it always prints "{", the last line of the file
    fputs(*(string_2 + 5), stdout);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `*(string_2 + 5)` instead of `string_2[5]` which matches the method you used elsewhere.

Comment: To train pointer's notation. It also doesn't work with string_2[5]

Comment: Hold on, in C, ` fputs()` has only two parameters, not three. It always outputs to the end of the string.

Comment: That was the problem in compiling, thanks! But still, it always prints "}", which is the last line of the code, for any i in string_2[i]. Do you know what is the error?

Comment: in general, do not cast the returned value from `malloc()`.  The returned type, in C, is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  All the cast is doing is cluttering the code

Comment: regarding the expression:  `sizeof( char )`  This is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding:

```
string_2[i] = string;
```

This always copies (ONLY) a pointer to `string`  so, all the entries in `string_2` point to `string` and `string` contains what ever was read last.

Suggest replacing that statement with:

```
strcpy( string_2[i], string );
```

regarding:

```
fputs(*(string_2 + 5), stdout);
```

when the `strcpy()` is implemented, then the call to `fputs()` will not work due to an extra de-reference. suggest:

```
fputs( string_2 + 5, stdout );
```

The posted code contains a massive memory leak.  To fix this suggest:  replace:

```
string_2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*)*1000);
```

with

```
string_2 = calloc( sizeof( char *), 1000 );
```

so all the pointers in `string_2` contain NULL, then insert the following just before the `return` statement:

```
for( int i=0; i<MAX_INPUT_LINES; i++ )
{
    free( string_2[i] );
}
free( string_2 );
```

Note:  the function: `free()` handles a NULL parameter with no problems.

for robust code, regarding this kind of statement:

```
string_2[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
```

always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Note: `1000` is a 'magic' number.  To use a meaningful name, suggest:

```
#define MAX_INPUT_LINES 1000
```

Then use the name: `MAX_INPUT_LINES` when calling `calloc()`

Do a similar name when allocating room for each line from the input file.

The code should stop inputting lines if there is more than 1000 lines in the input file.  suggest replacing:

```
while (fgets(string, 1000, file_1)!= NULL)
```

with:

```
while ( i < MAX_INPUT_LINES && fgets(string, 1000, file_1)!= NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! As for the suggestion to change *( string_2 + 5) to  string_2 + 5, wouldn't it string_2 + 5 be the address of the pointer and *(string_2 + 5) the pointer itself?    Also, what's the difference between using calloc and malloc in this case? Regarding the memory leak, is there a way I can know exactly the size of each line of the code so as to not guess an arbitraty big size (1000)?

Comment: the lines were read with `fgets()` which always appends a NUL byte to the input.  So `strlen( string )` will return the offset to the NUL byte.  Always add 1 to that returned value to know how many bytes to allocate

Comment: As for the fact that attributing an array to another, it always happens that they both always have this "link" that when I change one the other also changes? Cause when I attribute a variable y to another variable x, and then change y, x usually doesn't change.

Comment: the array `string_2[]` contains nothing but NULL values and pointers to the allocated char array that will contain the line read from the file.  De-referencing in the call to `strcpy()` will result in the first parameter containing the allocated memory rather than a pointer to where that allocated memory is located

Comment: the function: `malloc()` does not initialize the allocated memory.  the function: `calloc()` initializes the allocated memory to all '\0'

Comment: Suggest just running your code with both methods to see which one actually works correctly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you are assigning data to your `string_2` array. In your read loop, you do this:

```c
string_2[i] = string;
```

Which is assigning to the *pointer* that is `string_2[i]` the value of the *pointer* that is `string`. So, when you later change the *data* in `string`, you will also change the data pointed to by each, previously-assigned, `string_2[i]` pointer.  Thus, when your loop ends, all the `string_2[]` pointers will point to the (same) `string` data.

What you should do instead, in your loop, is this:

```c
strcpy(string_2[i], string);
```

This will copy the ***current data*** in `string` to your indexed and (correctly) allocated new `string_2[i]` buffer.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.